# Jack compiler and java 8 make Android apps grabled

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, jack-compiler

When I started to use jack compiler and java 8 to develop an Android app, I found the normal words become garbled like this:

[image]

This text should be a Chinese, but it became garbled. And this is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.li.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

But when I don't use the jack compiler and java 8, the garbled text returned to normal:

[image]

All I have done is deleting the `jackOptions` and `compileOptions` in the `build.gradle`.

My file encoding is `UTF-8`.

How can I avoid the garbled text when I use jack and java 8 ? Or is this a bug ?

Comment: I found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215729), which looks similar to what you're describing.

Comment: you can discard specifying compileOptions in gradle. try once use jack option alone

Comment: @Michael yes, it's the same question. So I think this maybe a bug of Jack compiler. And, even I only use option without `compileOptions`, this question still appears.  @HourGlass

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218892